# Median of large numbers of gaussian has gaussian distribution

Tags: probability

Prove that for large n, median of n independent Gaussian data with mean $\mu$ and variance $ \sigma ^ 2 $ has approximately normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $ ((\pi * (\sigma)^2 ) / (2*n) ) $ . What about non-gaussian data?

This is a homework. I think I should use the central law theorem or law of large numbers.

Comment: Do you know how to answer this if the data comes from some other sampling distribution?

Comment: No. I think this is a hard question. The proof of the law of large numbers was hard itself. The easy one was by using martingales. Maybe it can be proved if we could control the distance between the mean and median. But I don't think that this happens for all distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly abridged from Bain and Englehardt: *Intro to probability theory and mathematical statistics,* Sect 7.4. (Asymptotic Distribution of Central Order Statistics.)

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample from a continuous PDf $f(x)$ that
is continuous and nonzero at the $p$th percentile $x_p,$ for $0 < p < 1.$
If $k/n \rightarrow p$ (with $k =np$ bounded), then the sequence of the $k$th order statistics $X_{k:n}$ is asymptotically normal with mean $x_p$ and
variance $c^2/n,$ where $c^2 = \frac{p(1-p)}{[f(x_p)]^2}.$ (A proof for a
specific non-normal case is given.) Notice that the theorem does not apply to the maximum or minimum.

The version for the sample median is sometimes called the CLT for the sample median.
The condition for the usual CLT for sample *means* is that $Var(X_i)$ is finite.
This corresponding theorem for sample medians requires that the PDF is not
$0$ in the vicinity of the population median $\eta,$ so that a unique population median exists.

For example, if $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Exp}(1),$ then the sample median is asymptotically normal with mean $\ln 2$ and asymptotic variance $1/n.$

The following simulation in R illustrates that $n = 100$ is not quite a large
enough sample size for a really good fit of sample medians to $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=\log 2,\, \sigma=1/10).$ (The distribution of sample medians $H$ is slightly right-skewed.)

```
m = 10^5; n = 100
h = replicate(m, median(rexp(n)))
mean(h);  sd(h)
## 0.6982754  # compare ln 2 = 0.693
## 0.09977901 # compare .1
hist(h, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Sample Medians of Sample of 100 from EXP(1)")
curve(dnorm(x, log(2), sqrt(1/n)), add=T, lwd=2)
abline(v=log(2), lwd=2, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I got my answer! and do you have any idea for the proof?

Comment: Sorry, I have never seen a proof of the general theorem. Only for special cases such as uniform and exponential. Not an area with which I'm really familiar. Also I don't know the level of your course or what you've studying lately. Maybe order statistics, maybe limit theorems. Context might be a guide. Without context, I'd start by looking at Kendall, Stuart & Ord which has some possibly relevant results on normal order statistics.

Comment: No special context. It is a master's course in mathematics. Thank you.